# Edit supplementary text on bounty

Tags: feature-request

I recently placed a bounty on [this question about the "double possessive"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of), but just realised I wanted to make a minor (but to me, significant) change to my "supplementary text" in the *"This question has an open bounty..."* box.

So far as I can see, there's no facility for doing this. Can we have one?

Comment: @Daniel: I never paid for anything. And not only did those nice people at SE give me a free t-shirt - they gave me another one 'cos they spelt *stackxchange* wrong on the first one!

Comment: I find myself in a similar predicament with this question [Usage of to find](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/132201/44619) My fault I should have read the OP's question more carefully I guess. I was particularly interested in his 2nd one, which I interpreted his "that" to refer to **find + object + to be** construction. (Don't really know why I'm commenting here. I don't want to write a meta question, I suppose).